# Extracting Miner Data in Google BigQuery for Bitcoin

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract the miner data in the Bitcoin Google BigQuery dataset.

The miner data is the first index inside the outputs transactions. It should be the first index of `addresses` of `outputs` as shown in the documentation here: https://www.kaggle.com/bigquery/bitcoin-blockchain?select=outputs

I've written an SQL Query to try an extract that but it seems to error out on Google BigQuery with `Response too large to return. Consider setting allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration.`

I am not sure if it's an issue with my SQL query but I pasted it below:

```
select array_to_string(outputs.addresses,',') as address,
       t.block_number,
       t.block_timestamp,
       t.block_hash,
       outputs.index from bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions t join unnest(outputs) as outputs
where outputs.index = 0
order by block_number asc
```

I am trying to specify only when the index is 0 do we get the first address in outputs.addresses and that is a variable we can save as "miner". I just don't know if my approach is right or if there's a better way to do this in SQL.

Hoping for some guidance on this.

Comment: is it in BQ Console?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant yes in BQ Console.

Comment: legacy or standard sql? it is not clear from the query you presented.

Comment: My bad, it's standard sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use destination table so result of your query (Don't forget to remove ORDER BY though) will be stored in table that then you will be able to query further.

Or you can use `INSERT INTO ... AS` approach